# C Bitwise Operators Example

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

given the following function:

```
int boof(int n) {
    return n + ~n + 1;
}
```

What does this function return? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what is being passed in to it. If I called boof(10), would it convert 10 to base 2, and then do the bitwise operations on the binary number?

This was a question I had on a quiz recently, and I think the answer is supposed to be 0, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

note: I know how each bitwise operator works, I'm more confused on how the input is processed.

Thanks!

Comment: 10 is converted to base 2 by compiler, so yes answer is 0

Comment: Okay so it would be 1010 + 0101 which gives 1111. Then 1111 + 0001 which results in 1111. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *All* data in a modern computer is stored in binary, i.e. base 2. To find out what it does, write down the number you pass on a piece of paper as binary, then perform the operations on it on paper, remembering that you're most likely on a system using the [two's complement system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: @EmiliaClarke You forget that `int` is most likely 32 bits, not four. And, seemingly, that normal addition is not the same as a bitwise OR.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg hmm..I'm still a bit confused. I realize now that I was mistaking regular addition for the bitwise OR, but even now I can't seem to get 0. 10 + 5 + 1 = 16. 16 in 2's complement is just 10000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise operations will not change the underlying representation of the number to base 2 - all math on the CPU is done using binary operations regardless.

What this function does is take n and then add it to the two's complement negative representation of itself. This essentially negates the input. Anything you put in will equal 0.

Let me explain with 8 bit numbers as this is easier to visualize.

10 is represented in binary as 00001010.

Negative numbers are stored in two's complement (NOTing the number and adding 1)

So the (~n + 1) portion for 10 looks like so:

> 11110101 + 1 = 11110110

So if we take n + ~n+1:

> 00001010 + 11110110 = 0

Notice if we add these numbers together we get a left carry which will set the overflow flag, resulting in a 0. (Adding a negative and positive number together never means the overflow indicates an exception!)

See this 
[The CARRY and OVERFLOW flag in Binary Arithmetic](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt)

Comment: Okay, it clicked. Thanks for the explanation! Wish me luck on my final exam tomorrow :D

Answer (score 3):

When `n` is an `int`, `n + ~n` will always result in an `int` that has all bits set.

Strictly speaking, the behavior of adding 1 to such an `int` will depend on the representation of signed numbers on the platform. The C standard support 3 representations for `signed int`:

- for Two's Complement machines (the vast majority of systems in use today), the result will be 0 since an `int` with all bits set is -1.
- on a One's Complement machine (which are pretty rare today, I believe), the result will be 1 since an `int` with all bits set is 0 or -0 (negative zero) or undefined behavior.
- a Signed-magnitude machine (are there really any of these still in use?), an `int` with all bits set is a negative number with the maximum magnitude (so the actual value will depend on the size of an `int`).  In this case adding 1 to it will result in a negative number (the exact value, again depends on the number of bits that are used to represent an `int`).

Note that the above ignores that it might be possible for some implementations to trap with various bit configurations that might be possible with `n + ~n`.

Comment: `n | ~n` would result in setting all bits but `n + ~n` only does so in the 2's complement case

Comment: The only time I used a 1's complement machine was back in college.  My recollection was that adding a number with it's bit inverse resulted in negative zero (which behaved the same as zero for pretty much all purposes) - all bits set. On looking at the standard, it says: "It is unspecified whether these cases actually generate a negative zero or a normal zero,and whether a negative zero becomes a normal zero when stored in an object", so it seems that either behavior is OK.

Comment: Also, accurately covering all the nuances that could theoretically occur for something like this would really boil down to copy/pasting a chunk of the standard.  All I was really trying to do was point out that there's technically not one 'correct' answer, even though I'm pretty sure the one that's being looked for is "zero".

Comment: @sfstewman It is not undefined behavior. Look at the order of operations here. The unary not happens first. This means we are always adding a positive to a negative number, and THEN adding 1. There is no overflow.